# Firebase: keep data local until login

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to keep all the data local, and sync it online with firebase when the user decide to login in to the app?

I know about the offline capabilities of firebase, but I don't think they are meant for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd use an anonymous login for that situation. The data will be synchronized with the Firebase server in that case, but the user doesn't have to sign in yet. For more information, see the [documentation on anonymous auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).